# React.JS Alert: How to Automate Disappearance After 2 Seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, react-hooks

Make my alert disappear after 2 seconds in React.JS
I am trying to make this disappear after 2 seconds. However, this only disappears if I close it ( fecharAlerta props is a close function)

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useState } from "react"
import { FaCheck, FaExclamationTriangle, FaInfo, } from "react-icons/fa"
import { HiX } from "react-icons/hi"
import "./css/alerta.css"
function Alerta({ tipo, mostrar, mensagem, fecharAlerta }) {
    const [cor, setCor] = useState()
    useEffect(function () {
        if (tipo === "sucesso") {
            setCor("rgb(74, 112, 74)")
        }
        if (tipo === "erro") {
            setCor("rgb(138, 67, 67)")
        }
        if (tipo === "info") {
            setCor("rgb(185, 184, 93)")
        }
    }, [tipo])
    if (mostrar === true) {
        return (
            <div className="alerta" style={{ backgroundColor: cor }}>
                {tipo === "sucesso" &&
                    <FaCheck className="icon" />
                }
                {tipo === "erro" &&
                    <FaExclamationTriangle className="icon" />
                }
                {tipo === "info" &&
                    <FaInfo className="icon" />
                }
                <span className="titulo">{mensagem}</span>
                <div><button className="fechar-btn" onClick={fecharAlerta}><HiX /></button></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return null
    }
}
export default Alerta
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the dismissal functionality, a new `useEffect` hook is used.

In the modified code, the second `useEffect` hook is responsible for setting up a timeout when the component is mounted. It uses the `setTimeout` function to schedule the `fecharAlerta` callback function to be executed after 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds). This ensures that the alert will automatically be dismissed after the specified time.

To clean up the timeout and prevent any memory leaks, the `useEffect` hook returns a cleanup function that calls `clearTimeout` with the timeout reference. This ensures that the timeout is cleared if the component is unmounted.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { FaCheck, FaExclamationTriangle, FaInfo, } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { HiX } from 'react-icons/hi';
import './css/alerta.css';

function Alerta({ tipo, mostrar, mensagem, fecharAlerta }) {
  const [cor, setCor] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tipo === "sucesso")
      setCor("rgb(74, 112, 74)");
    else if (tipo === "erro")
      setCor("rgb(138, 67, 67)");
    else if (tipo === "info")
      setCor("rgb(185, 184, 93)");
  }, [tipo]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(fecharAlerta, 2000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [fecharAlerta]);

  return mostrar ? (
    <div className="alerta" style={{ backgroundColor: cor }}>
      {tipo === "sucesso" ? <FaCheck className="icon" /> : null}
      {tipo === "erro" ? <FaExclamationTriangle className="icon" /> : null}
      {tipo === "info" ? <FaInfo className="icon" /> : null}
      <span className="titulo">{mensagem}</span>

      <div>
        <button className="fechar-btn" onClick={fecharAlerta}>
          <HiX />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null;
}

export default Alerta
```